# Google scholar "cited by" redirects to a paper not citing the original

Tags: google-scholar

Consider the following [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=on%20integer%20solutions%20of%20quadratic%20equations&btnG=&oq=on%20integer%20solutions). Click on the first result "On integer solutions of quadratic equations" -> "cited by 20". You arrive to [this page](https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?cites=17687840550242195345&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en). This page should list the papers that cite the aformentionned. However, see the papers cited by the first result "Most Tensor Problems Are NP-Hard". I cannot find the original paper cited there. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Scholar's behavior with citations is sometimes rather weird when multiple indexed versions of a paper are involved. It certainly doesn't only count citations in the final and published version. Here I think Google Scholar may have picked up this citation link from the [third arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1393v3.pdf) of "Most Tensor Problems are NP-Hard". As far as I can see, this version of the preprint doesn't actually cite "On integer solutions of quadratic equations" in the text, yet has it in the list of references, presumably included by mistake. (The earlier and subsequent versions listed on arXiv do not include the reference at all.)